# Dropdown options show in light color after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento

if you visit [here](http://sb2.kidsdial.com/) , on top right, we can see `र - INR.`

once we hover on that it will display options in normal color . that's fine.

[image]

if you take mouse away and again hover for some times, if you keep repeating this for sometimes,

than it will display options in light color :

[image]

**phtml**

```
<div class="form-language">
    <ul id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?>" class="dropDownMenu">
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $selCurrency ?></a>
        <ul>
            <?php echo $lis ?>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#select-language li').hover(function() {
            jQuery(this).children('ul').stop(true, false, true).fadeToggle(300);
        });
    });
```

**css**

```
.menuBackground {
    background: brown;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropDownMenu a {
    color: #FFF;
}
.dropDownMenu,
.dropDownMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropDownMenu li {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    text-align:left;
}
.dropDownMenu a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropDownMenu a:first-child { 
color: #000; 
font-weight:bold;
}

.dropDownMenu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: -4px; /* solve the 4 pixels spacing between list-items */
}
.dropDownMenu > li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.dropDownMenu ul {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}
.dropDownMenu > li > ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 120px;
    z-index: 999999;
}

.dropDownMenu li a:hover {
    background: #ff7704; /*Your color*/
    color: #000; /*Your color*/
}
```

Comment: I would say your jQuery fade effect causes this bug. You should set opacity to 1 if it is visible.

Comment: @Jurik are you telling to change `fadeToggle(300);` to `fadeToggle(1);`

Comment: No - `fadeToggle(300)` means it toggles in 300ms. I guess @Gaurav's answer might be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See whats happening is when you hover mouse on it, your function runs and who are using `fadeToggle(300)` which slows down the function. So this bug will not come if you hover and stay the mouse on the element and then gently remove it after a while.

But you should not bound use to do so, hence you should try using this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#select-language li').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).children('ul').fadeIn();
    }, function(){
        jQuery(this).children('ul').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change this line in this way:

```
jQuery(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(300);
```